# How can I select an Animatedmodal to display different demos using one ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that i am trying to personalize and I am trying to use the `AnimatedModal.js` framework. I have been able to display some content in one modal, but when it comes to make several modal it gets tricky, because there is just one ID. My question i, how can i use the same ID and change the content for other modals(demo03,demo04..etc.), in order to personalize each.

I will put some code in order to understand the problem

I have been reading the documentation but I am still stuck in this problem.

```
<!-- single work -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 ads graphics"> 
  <a id="demo02" href="#animatedModal" class="portfolio_item"> 
    <img src="img/portfolio/03.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
    <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
      <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
        <div class="item_info"> 
          <span>Should open here </span> <em> ads / Graphics </em> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- end single work -->
```

Then I have the demo where it displays the content of the modal, where it has the #animatedmodal ID

```
<div id="animatedModal" class="popup-modal ">
<!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID -->
  <div id="btn-close-modal" class="close-animatedModal close-popup-modal"> 
    <i class="ion-close-round"></i> 
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="modal-content ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="portfolio-padding" >
        Hello World
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my Js file where there is just one element assigned to it, to avoid showing the same content into all different classes.

```
$("#demo02").animatedModal();
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly: `it gets tricky, because there is just one ID`?

Comment: What happens when you replace `$("#demo02").animatedModal();` with `$(".portfolio_item").animatedModal();`? You should be able to call it via the class, then you can have the `href` be different ids

Comment: Because I am trying to build new demos with the same animatedModal ID and it seems that it is showing only the first one that you create for all the entries(single work) without even displaying the other ones. My question is, how can i create new demos and assign them to different entries. in here $("#demo02").animatedModal();  i can just put #demo02 to display once, if i put more it will display on every demo i put the same.

Comment: @IanMillan that's expected, elements ID must be unique. As @imvalin2 said, you can use a common selector like `.portfolio_item` to bind the function.

Comment: id should be unique per page.  you can use name instead. get a collection and foreach on it if you want to display all of them.  if you want to display only one at a time then you need a nother criteria to discriminate them like having unique ids

Comment: @imvain2 how can i have the href calling different ids? Can you elaborate this a little more?  from the single work or demo? Thanks for this help!!! , I am stuck on here and i tried many things.

Comment: `<a id="demo02" href="#animatedModal" class="portfolio_item">...</a>`, `<a id="demo03" href="#animatedModal3" class="portfolio_item">...</a>`, `<a id="demo04" href="#animatedModal4" class="portfolio_item">...</a>`, etc.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I guess i have to add the $("#demo03").animatedModal2(); into the js file too?

Comment: As imvain2 wrote above, you can bind it to elements common class like this `$(".portfolio_item").animatedModal();` this should work for every <a> with class portfolio_item

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I got that part, but when i am trying to create a demo(the second part of the code) i choose    `id="animatedModal" href="#demo01"` and it displays again all of the other entries with the same message. I created another demo which is  `id="animatedModal2" href="#demo02"`  and it is not displaying. That is why i was asking if i should update the .js file.

Comment: @IanMillan I'll try and answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done without hacking the plugin.

As a matter of fact, the script jQuery.animatedModal ALWAYS TARGETS the page element which has `id="animatedModal"`

You can see the plugin source code here:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animatedmodal@1.0.0/animatedModal.js

```
...
//Defaults
var settings = $.extend({
  modalTarget:'animatedModal',
 ...
```

Here is the AnimatedModal reference:

https://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/

At the bottom of the page, I can't see any OPTION regarding how to specify a different target, all options are about styles and animation features.

At this point, I think the only way to allow multiple modals on the same page is to rewrite the plugin, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to choose this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is weird how it only allows you to display the same data for all the modals that you make. I will see if i can do something to change this. Regards!

Comment: @IanMillan allright, if you want to check Featherlight [https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/] it is a pretty versatile alternative

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!